# selenium java chromedriver URL not opening

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run selenium in java using chromedriver.I am getting the following error.Any help is much appreciated. Its opening the chrome browser but given url is not opening. Line `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);` is giving the error.
OS Version: Mac Bigsur
Selenium : 4.1.2
Chrome:99.0.4844.74
Chromedriver:99.0.4844.5

Exception is :
[Either(left): org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: was killed.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '4.1.2', revision: '9a5a329c5a'

```
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Command: [null,
newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --disable-extensions, --headless, --disable-gpu, --no-sandbox, --no-sandbox, --incognito, --disable-application-cache, --disable-dev-shm-usage], extensions: []}}],
desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --disable-extensions, --headless, --disable-gpu, --no-sandbox, --no-sandbox, --incognito, --disable-application-cache, --disable-dev-shm-usage], extensions: []}}}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:558)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:245)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:82)
    at com.automation.Launch_Chrome.main(Launch_Chrome.java:28)


Code:
WebDriver driver = null;

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/Caskroom/chromedriver/99.0.4844.51/chromedriver");
        String URL = "https://www.google.com";
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);
        List<String> arguments = new LinkedList<>();
        arguments.add("--disable-extensions");
        arguments.add("--headless");
        arguments.add("--disable-gpu");
        arguments.add("--no-sandbox");

        arguments.add("--no-sandbox");
        arguments.add("--incognito");
        arguments.add("--disable-application-cache");
        arguments.add("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        chromeOptions.addArguments(arguments);
        try {
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.get(URL);

<dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency>   
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your full code (at least up to the point where you hit the exception)? It might be that you've set up `chromeOptions` wrong. Also, can you please double-check that you've got the full exception details? Your exception includes a stack trace and some info about the driver setup, but the type of exception thrown and the message it contains are both missing.

Comment: when i debug thorough the code .i got the below error.                          [Either(left): org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: was killed.
  (chrome not reachable)